# Refreshing the list in react when added an item to it

Tags: reactjs

I have two components in react one is a list and other is a form to update the list. I want to update the list when the item is added through the form. I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

To achieve that i created a parent component and declared the function to fetch the items in that and i passing the function in both of the child components the form and the list and calling the function when the form is submitted.

Please let me know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: See useState() in the react document. Keep state and update it, then re-rendering works.